# How to add a set number of days to a date in MS Project VBA without counting non-working time

Tags: vba, project, ms-project

I am trying to set the deadline for a task by taking the amount of slack from the finish date.  Thus, I need to be add or take days from the finish and not count any non-working time.

DateAdd includes non-working time. For instance if I set the deadline for 7 days before the finish (11/10/22) I expect the deadline to be 30/09, giving a slack of -7.

However using t.finish = dateadd("d",slack,t.finish) gives 04/10 with a finish of 11/10

I have tried Application.ProjDateAdd(t.Finish, slack, "standard") however VBA doesn't like this.

Comment: Oddly I have tried dateadd("w" which should give weekday however it has the same outcome of 04/10.

Comment: I have tried converting the days to a fraction of a week however the calculation is only using the integer element (1 = 1.25 = 1.9).  I have defined slack as double.  I tried long as the article below stated that if not saved as long it would be rounded but that didn't make any difference.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dateadd-function

Answer (score 0):

To:

> add or take days from the finish and not count any non-working
> time

use the Project Application methods [DateAdd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.dateadd) and [DateSubtract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.application.datesubtract):

```
Sub SetDeadline()

    Dim cal As Calendar
    Set cal = ActiveProject.Calendar
    
    Dim t As Task
    For Each t In ActiveProject.Tasks
        If t.TotalSlack > 0 Then
            t.Deadline = Application.DateAdd(t.Finish, t.TotalSlack, cal)
        Else
            t.Deadline = Application.DateSubtract(t.Finish, -t.TotalSlack + 480, cal)
            t.Deadline = Application.DateAdd(t.Deadline, 480, cal)
        End If
    Next t
    
End Sub
```

Also, take a look at [Late Finish](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/late-finish-task-field-3e47febb-92b5-4d0b-94c5-b6b1ab70e8c1) which is the latest date that a task can finish without delaying the finish of the project.

Comment: Note that Project's DateAdd function is different than VBA's DateAdd, thus preface calls to DateAdd with the application object: `Application.DateAdd(...`.

Comment: @rachael Hettinger Thank you for that, I didn't know about the subtract function.  Oddly when I use this I get 08:00 on the day after the expected deadline.  operationally this is the same thing however when people read it they could be mislead.  Do I added a slight change:  t.deadline = Application.datasubtract(t.finish, -t.totalSlack+0.6,cal) which forces it to 16:59 the previous day which is when the eye expects the deadline to be.  Thanks :)

Comment: @Miles Ah, DateSubtract yields an 8:00 AM date the next day whereas DateAdd gives 5:00 PM as expected. I updated the code to subtract an extra day and then add that day to get to the expected finish at the end of the day (e.g. 5:00 PM).